# OAuth2 library for objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, oauth-2.0

Good Afternoon,

Any one have any suggestions for an OAuth2 cocoa pod that is currently being maintained for Objective-c. We have been using OAuthSwift but we are having trouble with the latest builds and XCode8 so we were thinking a native objective-c pod would be better

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Did you find anything ?

Comment: I didn't. I worked with the OAuthSwift owner and we created a swift3.0objc branch which contains a bridge method to work with objective-c. You can take a look at that

Comment: Thank you for your response.